# HTML form sends the wrong database ID PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I made a user system for my website. If you open it you well see a list of all users and you can lock or unlock them by changing "n_gesperrt" in the database to 1 or 0. 1 means locked.
The form you see here is always sending the last user id (n_id) to the php script on the top. So if I want to change something it only works with the last user shown on the list.
How can I solve that problem?
These are the code pieces:

THE FORM:

```
    while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
 {  
echo "<form name=\"nutzer_sperren\" method=\"POST\" action=\"index.php?page=nutzer_sperren\">";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"n_id\" value=\"".$zeile['n_id']."\">";
    echo $zeile['n_id'];
        if($zeile['n_gesperrt'] == 0){
            echo "<input type =\"submit\" name=\"sperren\" value=\"Nutzer sperren\">";
        }
        else {
            echo "<input type =\"submit\" name=\"entsperren\" value=\"Nutzer entsperren\">";
        }
    echo '</form">';
```

THE EDITING IN DATABASE:

```
        if(isset($_POST['sperren']))
{   
    $sperrung = mysqli_real_escape_string($verbinde, 1);
    mysqli_query($verbinde, 'UPDATE nutzer SET n_gesperrt ="'.$sperrung.'" WHERE n_id ='.$_POST["n_id"].'') or die(mysqli_error($verbinde));
    echo "Daten wurden erfolgreich geändert. <br>Bitte aktualisieren Sie die Seite!";
    echo $_POST["n_id"];
    echo "<hr>";
}



if(isset($_POST['entsperren']))
{
    $entsperren = mysqli_real_escape_string($verbinde, 0);
    mysqli_query($verbinde, 'UPDATE nutzer SET n_gesperrt ="'.$entsperren.'" WHERE n_id ='.$_POST["n_id"].'') or die(mysqli_error($verbinde));
    echo "Daten wurden erfolgreich geändert. <br>Bitte aktualisieren Sie die Seite!";
    echo $_POST["n_id"];
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

Comment: Holly molly, man, don't name your variables in your native language, always use english, otherwise only ask stackoverflow.de for help. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things you need to change in your code, such as:

- > ... The form you see here is always sending the last user id (n_id) to the php script on the top. So if I want to change something it only works with the last user shown on the list.

  That's because you've assigned the same `name` attribute for all of your *hidden* input elements. Change your `name` attribute in the following way,

  ```
   ... name='n_id[]' ...
  ```
- Change the `name` attribute of *submit* elements to just `submit`, because in this way you don't have to use two separate `if` blocks to handle user's response.
- Remove the double quote from `echo '</form">';`, otherwise your form would break.

So your `while()` loop should be like this:

```
while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    echo "<form method='POST' action='index.php?page=nutzer_sperren'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='n_id[]' value='".$zeile['n_id']."'>";
    if($zeile['n_gesperrt'] == 0){
        echo "<input type ='submit' name='submit' value='Nutzer sperren'>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<input type ='submit' name='submit' value='Nutzer entsperren'>";
    }
    echo '</form>';  
}
```

Furthermore, as I said above, you don't have to use two separate `if` blocks, just use one `if` block to check whether the form is submitted or not and toggle the *n_gesperrt* column value in your `UPDATE` operation, like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    mysqli_query($verbinde, 'UPDATE nutzer SET n_gesperrt = IF(n_gesperrt = 1, 0, 1) WHERE n_id ='.$_POST["n_id"][0]) or die(mysqli_error($verbinde));
    echo "Daten wurden erfolgreich geändert. <br>Bitte aktualisieren Sie die Seite!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bro use name as array 
like below and you will get your result in array

```
     while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
     {  
    echo "<form name=\"nutzer_sperren\" method=\"POST\" action=\"index.php?page=nutzer_sperren\">";
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"n_id[]\" value=\"".$zeile['n_id']."\">";
        echo $zeile['n_id'];
            if($zeile['n_gesperrt'] == 0){
                echo "<input type =\"submit\" name=\"sperren[]\" value=\"Nutzer sperren\">";
            }
            else {
                echo "<input type =\"submit\" name=\"entsperren[]\" value=\"Nutzer entsperren\">";
            }
        echo '</form">';
```

on submission page get value like
    $name=$_POST['entsperren'];

```
print_r($name);
```